# Insert new row to SQL DB using Stored Procedure and two parameters

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to insert a new row to SQL DB using a stored procedure that takes two parameters. I am using an asp.net gridview and checkboxes in the first column so that you can select the row. For each row that is selected, it will insert the new row which supplies the ProjectID. The CorpID is provided with the query string. I commented out some of the lines in my code because it is giving me errors and I am not sure how to do the rest. I am following a video on YouTube to get this done. In the video, they are deleting rows but I am attempting to insert rows. If anyone wants the link to the video it is [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r2V5VXrFoFk). Here is my code from the DataAccessLayer

```
public void AssociateCorpToProj(ProjectData pd) 
{
    using(SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(_dbConnection)) 
    {
        using(SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("InsertProjectEntity", cn)) 
        {
            cm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cn.Open();
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectID", pd.ProjectID);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CorpID", pd.CorpID);
            cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my code for my code behind that calls the method from the DataAccessLayer

```
protected void btnAssociateProjects_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    List < object > lstCorpProjAssoc = new List < object> ();
    foreach(GridViewRow gvRow in gvProjects.Rows) 
    {
        if (((CheckBox) gvRow.FindControl("cbInsert")).Checked) 
        {
            string cID = ((Label) gvRow.FindControl("lblProjectID")).Text;
            lstCorpProjAssoc.Add(cID);
        }
    }

    foreach(ProjectData str in lstCorpProjAssoc)
    {
        DALSectionAccessData ap = new DALSectionAccessData(connString);
        ProjectData pd = new ProjectData();
        ap.AssociateCorpToProj(str);

    }

}
```

In case anyone thinks they need the code for the stored procedure, here it is.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ProjectEntity]
     ([ProjectID],[CorpID])
VALUES
     (@ProjectID, @CorpID)
```

Also, the list class that I am using

```
public class ProjectData
{
public string CompanyName { get; set; }
public int ProjectID { get; set; }
public int CorpID { get; set; }
}
```

Let me know if you need more information to answer the question. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The problem is that I am using a List string in my onclick for the button I am using. The error is `"The best overloaded method match for SectionAccessData.AssociateCorpToProj(Entities.ProjectData) has some invalid arguments"`

Comment: `List < string > lstCorpProjAssoc = new List < string > ();` I think that you want to add a List<ProjectData> 

so something like this 
`List<ProjectData> lstCorpProjAssoc = new  List<ProjectData>();` from there add each class object to a List<T>

Comment: When I try that, I get the error: `Cannot convert type 'Entities.ProjectData' to 'string'`
I get this error on the line where I put the label text to cID. Which, by the way, I made cID to ProjectData. So now that line of code is `ProjectData cID = ((Label)gvRow.FindControl("Label2")).Text;`

Comment: declare the List<T> that will hold the List<ProjectData> as an object like this 
List <object> lstCorpProjAssoc = new List <object> (); and the Class List<T> like this
`List<ProjectData> lstProjectData = new List<ProjectData>();`

Comment: I have no error running it this way you will get that error if you do not create the new instance inside of a loop for the ProjectData.. and load it's new instance into the list.. also if this is a web app try to hold the Label2.text value in hidden field or session variable etc check viewstate as well for that Label2

Comment: you could initialize the List this way initially then 
assign the values then add to the other list
`List<object> lstCorpProjAssoc = new List<object>()
            {
               string.Empty,
               0,
               0
            };`

Comment: I just double checked the name of the label and it was wrong. Sorry about that but the error I am getting now is `Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'Entities.ProjectData'`
That error comes up for the second foreach loop. The one that is commented out above in my initial code. That one is now set to ProjectData though. So now it is. 
`foreach (ProjectData pstr in lstCorpProjAssoc)
  {
       DALSectionAccessData ap = new DALSectionAccessData(connString);
                ProjectData pd = new ProjectData();
                ap.AssociateCorpToProj(pstr);

            }`

Comment: can you edit you code and show what you have thus far I think that you are getting confused on the difference between List<Class> and List<object> you are wanting to store 1 string and 2 integers in a List<T> then the List<T> must be declared as List<object>

Comment: I have made the edits.

Comment: I am going to post some code that I want you to put inside of a Console app, Step through it and understand what it is I am doing .. this will give you a complete idea on what you need to do to make your class Data work when you want to store a List<ProjectData> ok this will be for your learning purposes you just have to follow the same concept when doing it for your code hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the code in the DataAccessLayer:

```
public void AssociateCorpToProj(int pd, int cd) 
{
    using(SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(_dbConnection)) 
    {
        using(SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("InsertProjectEntity", cn)) 
        {
            cm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cn.Open();
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectID", pd);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CorpID", cd);
            cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

For the code for the code behind that calls the method from the DataAccessLayer:

```
protected void btnAssociateProjects_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    List < int > lstCorpProjAssoc = new List < int > ();
    foreach(GridViewRow gvRow in gvProjects.Rows) 
    {
        if (((CheckBox) gvRow.FindControl("cbInsert")).Checked) 
        {
            int cID = Convert.ToInt32(((Label) gvRow.FindControl("lblProjectID")).Text);
            lstCorpProjAssoc.Add(cID);
        }
    }
    foreach(int pstr in lstCorpProjAssoc) 
    {
        DALSectionAccessData ap = new DALSectionAccessData(connString);
        ap.AssociateCorpToProj(pstr, _cID);

    }
}
```

Not using the list class. I tested this out and it worked. The parameters are both `int` so it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this example and step through the code this will help you understand    `List<object> vs List<string> vs List<Class>`

```
var listAllData = new List<object>();
for (var cnt = 0; cnt< 10; cnt++)
{
    var lstProjectData = new List<object>() //you need to change yours to be new List<ProjectData>
    {
       string.Empty, //CompanyName
       0, //ProjectID
       0 //CorpId
    }; 

    lstProjectData [0] = string.Format("CompanyName {0}", cnt);
    lstProjectData [1] = cnt+ 1;
    lstProjectData [2] = cnt+ 2;
    listAllData.Add(lstProjectData );

//from your List<ProjectData> you should be able to get at the variable
//as follows someVariable.CompanyName = , 
//someVariable.ProjectId = , 
//and someVariable = CorpId
}
```

Comment: So I use this instead of ProjectData.cs (my list class from above)?

Comment: No you need to use List<ProjectData> declaring a new Instance inside of the for loop, then once you assign the value to the 3 fields then you need to call the `.Add` method of the List<object> and add the List<ProjectData> that you just populated.. that's why I said step through this example line by line and evaluate and put break points on the listAllData.Add line in my example.. also you can use my example as a replacement but you have to make sure you are assigning the proper values to company name , ProjectId and CorpId

Comment: This confused me. So I add this to my foreach loop that is in the button? I am still learning C#...